# How to use the crittercism error reporting library from behind a firewall?

Tags: android, firewall, crittercism

I'm using Crittercism error/crash reporting on internal android devices that are behind a firewall.
How should I configure my firewall to let the crittercism library send info to the server? (port, ...)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crittercism transfers data along **HTTPS** with **256-bit encryption**, as such it sends data via **port 443**.

Make sure that you allow **https://api.crittercism.com** and that's it!

Edit:

If you're using the HTML5 library, ensure that you allow **https://d1a62freaxhn7x.cloudfront.net/** as well for the CDN.